# Calculating arithmetic mean from a list

Tags: python

I have a question asking on calculating the arithmetic mean from random numbers appended into a list. Basically what we have to do is to simulate rolling of 1000 dice, by generating random numbers of 1 to 6 and store in in a list. Then from there on we calculate the arithmetic mean of the list. I have done it but I'm not sure if it's done correctly. Any mistakes pointed out is much appreciated :) Also we aren't allowed to use built in functions.

```
import random
numberList = []

count = 0
while count<1001:
    x= random.randrange(1,7)
    numberList.append(x)
    count += 1

    list_sum = 0
    for i in numberList:
        list_sum += i
print(list_sum/len(numberList))
```

Comment: *list_sum = 0* and following lines should not be indented, while loop could be replace by *for count in range(1000)*. Attention: you are collecting 1001 random numbers.

Comment: @guidot ah thanks a little mistake there on 1001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite verbose but correct nonetheless. Below, you can find a more *pythonic* solution:

```
import random

numberList = []
for _ in range(1000):
    numberList.append(random.randrange(1, 7))

# or simply using a list comprehension
# numberList = [random.randrange(1, 7) for _ in range(1000)]

print(sum(numberList)/len(numberList))  # I got 3.587, 3.556, 3.529 which is close to what you would expect (3.5)
```

Note that the solution proposed above saves memory as well as it does not define as many variables (`x`, `count`, `list_sum`)

Comment: thanks a lot. Understood :)

Answer (score 1):

As Ev. Kounis pointed out your solution is (almost - you are collecting 1001 numbers as is pointed out by guidot) correct. But you might want to have a look at some nice list comprehension to improve your understanding of Python. One possibility would be:

```
import random

numberList = [random.randrange(1,7) for _ in range(1000)] # Create 1000 random integers between 1 and 6
sum(numberList)/len(numberList) # Calculate the arithmetic mean
```

Comment: alright, understood. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to contribute another approach seeing as how you don't really need to store the result of the dice rolls in a list to calculate the average if that's all you need to do. This might be more memory efficient.

```
import random

count = 0.0
for i in range(1000):
    count += random.randrange(1,7)
print count / 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, using a popular python library called `numpy`.

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> print mean([randrange(1, 7) for _ in range(1000)])
3.465
```